# Build complex rails SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Im using postgreSQL. Need scope for getting recent jokes with punchlines_count. I already achieve this with my scope. What i need know is my punchline counter should not include punchlines that has warn_level > 1. Warn model has punchline_id and weight, weight == warn_level. Please help me build this query. 
Clarifications: Punchline warn could be with weight 1 or 2, or could have 2 warns with weight 1 each. If warn_level > 1 i should not count it in my scope. Thanks!

My models.

```
class Joke < ActiveRecord::Base
  COLUMNS = self.column_names.map{|c| "jokes.#{c}" }.join(', ') 
  has_many :punchlines, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :recent, :order => 'jokes.created_at DESC'
  scope :recent_jokes_with_punchline_counter, lambda { |limit|
                        select("#{Joke::COLUMNS}, COUNT(punchlines.id) as punchlines_count").
                                             joins(:punchlines).
                                             group(Joke::COLUMNS).limit(limit) }


end

class Punchline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :joke
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :warns
end


class Warn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :punchline
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "jokes", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "up_votes",    :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.integer  "down_votes",  :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.string   "cached_slug"
    t.integer  "popularity"
    t.boolean  "anonymous",   :default => false
    t.string   "shorten_url"
  end

  create_table "punchlines", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "joke_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "up_votes",    :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.integer  "down_votes",  :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.string   "cached_slug"
    t.boolean  "anonymous",   :default => false
  end

  create_table "warns", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "punchline_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "weight"
  end
end
```

Comment: Why did You not assign the bounty? This sucks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're better off approaching this by creating a `warn_level` field on `punchlines`.

Much like the `counter` that ActiveRecord magically gives you, we can do something similar.

```
add_column :punchlines, :warn_level, :integer, :default => 0

class Punchline < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_warn_level!
    self.update_attribute(:warn_level, self.warns.sum(:weight))
  end
end
```

When a warning is added you could manually call this method, or have an observer do it for you.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers

```
class WarnObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(model)
    if model.punchline
      model.punchline.update_warn_level!
    end
  end
end

# in your application.rb
config.active_record.observers = :warn_observer
```

With this in place your problem becomes much simpler,
we can do what you want with the following sql.

```
SELECT jobs.*, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM punchlines
  WHERE punchlines.job_id = jobs.id
  AND punchlines.warn_level <= 1
) AS punchline_count
```

This can be expressed in ActiveRecord

```
PUNCHLINE_COUNT = <<-SQL
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM punchlines
  WHERE punchlines.job_id = jobs.id
  AND punchlines.warn_level <= 1
SQL

def with_punchline_count
  select("jobs.*, (#{PUNCHLINE_COUNT}) AS punchline_count")
end
```

This looks pretty messy,
but I think you've set yourself a difficult problem.

Hope this works for you.

Note: you could also cache the post_count as a column following a similar approach.
But lets deal with this iteratively.

Comment: This solution stores redundant information violating normalization and introduces possible breakage of relational integrity where there is no need. All you need is a query.

Comment: Every pattern has its downsides. I can only suggest solutions that, providing you have proper testing in place, make the ongoing need to fiddle with sql statements, a little less dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Your query could look like this. I filled in where your question was not clear.

```
SELECT j.id, j.joke, j.created_at, sum(w.weight) AS warn_level
FROM   jokes j
LEFT   JOIN punchlines p ON p.joke_id = j.id
LEFT   JOIN warns w ON w.punchline_id = p.id
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
HAVING COALESCE(sum(w.weight), 0) <= 1
ORDER  BY j.created_at DESC
LIMIT  my_limit;
```

#### Edit after more info

Adapted table names and primary key names (Automatically generated primary keys in ActiveRecord are named `id`). The rest was a direct hit. :)

I use `LEFT JOIN` now to safeguard against cases where `jokes` have no `punchlines` or `punchlines` have no `warns` at all. Hence the `HAVING` clause has to catch that case with COALESCE(), or `jokes` would be excluded just for having no punchline.
<sub>On the other hand, maybe they *should*? No punchline? What a joke?!</sub>

#### Concerning GROUP BY

Up until PostgreSQL 9.0 you need to list all ungrouped columns of your `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Starting with PostgreSQL **9.1** you can simply write `GROUP BY j.id` to cover all columns of the table `jokes` (`id` being the primary key).
I wrote more about that topic here: [Is it possible to have an SQL query that uses AGG functions in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870148/is-it-possible-to-have-an-sql-query-that-uses-agg-functions-in-this-way/7871033#7871033)

Comment: thanks a lot! Your query looks right, i will check it later. Also schema added.

Comment: This is wrong. If a joke has 5 punchlines, each with 1 warning, it would not show the joke. I think the OP wanted to show such a joke, with 5 punchlines.

Comment: My version accumulates the weight over all punchlines. That is probably not as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think You meant this:

```
select j.id, j.created_at, j.joke, count(helper.joke_id) as punchline_count
from jokes j
left join(
    select pl.joke_id
    from punchlines pl
    left join warns w on w.punchline_id=pl.id
    group by 1
    having colaesce(sum(w.weight),0)<=1
) as helper on helper.joke_id=j.id
group by 1,2,3
order by 2 desc
limit SOME_LIMIT
```

Comment: Why would you post an almost identical dupe of my answer, just without explanation?

Comment: I guess you are right. Your interpretation is more plausible.