# Join and order distinct rows from two tables in 1:n relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have a database table `r_event` with columns:

```
event_start (date), 
event_stop (date),
insurance_id (integer)
```

and a table `r_insurance` with columns:

```
insurance_id serial primary key,
insurance_name (text)
```

Each insurance has several events linked by `insurance_id`.

I am trying to:
`SELECT insurance_id, insurance_name` - only 1 of each,
and order by the *biggest* `event_stop`:
`ORDER BY event_stop DESC NULLS LAST` -- ??

#### EXAMPLE

```
r_insurance (insurance_id, insurance_name)
1 | rca
2 | casco
3 | itp

r_event (insurance_id, event_start, event_stop)
1 | 12.10.2012 | 27.11.2012
1 | 07.05.2012 | 24.06.2012
2 | 21.01.2013 | 14.02.2013
```

#### The output should be:

```
1 | casco -- cause it has the event with the biggest event_stop  
2 | rca   -- cause it has the 1st event_stop after the biggest event_stop  
3 | itc   -- cause it doesn't have events
```

I edited my first draft, I want them to be ordered descending by the event with the biggest `event_stop` and `NULLS LAST`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: if there is many event to one insurance with event should be order by?

Comment: "only one" := only one of which? For which a corresponding r_event record exists (in a particular range of dates) ?

Comment: i noticed ppl say it can be done with GROUP BY but i dont quite know what does it do and how

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear.  In such cases it is useful to give example input data, and example output data; to show what you have, what you want, and how you want to get there.

Comment: Why wouldn't 2|rca be the first one in the output? Isn't February 14, 2013 the biggest event.stop?

Comment: I took the liberty to largely rewrite your question to clarify. Please edit if I didn't get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i.insurance_id, i.insurance_name, max(e.event_stop) latest_stop
FROM   r_insurance i
LEFT   JOIN r_event e USING (insurance_id)
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY latest_stop DESC NULLS LAST;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is essential to avoid losing rows from `r_insurance` that do not have related rows in `r_event` - `itc` in your example.
`ORDER BY` has do be `DESC`. Also, no comma before `NULLS LAST`.

In PostgreSQL 9.1, the primary key covers all non-aggregated columns of the table in the `SELECT` list, so you can simplify (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7871033/939860)):

```
SELECT i.insurance_id, i.insurance_name, max(e.event_stop) latest_stop
FROM   r_insurance i
LEFT   JOIN r_event e USING (insurance_id)
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY latest_stop DESC NULLS LAST;
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/03389/1)

Answer (score 1):

> "it can be done with GROUP BY but i dont quite know what does it do and how"

Group by takes a relation and divides it up into partitions with all of the rows having the same value.  From there, you will get a single row from each partition in the result relation; with aggregate functions taken over each partition instead of the whole thing.  You could probably formulate something like:

```
SELECT
 insurance_id,
 insurance_name,
 max(stop) max_stop
FROM r_event JOIN r_insurance
 ON r_event.insurance_id = r_insurance.insurance_id
GROUP BY insurance_id, insurance_name
ORDER BY max_stop, NULLS LAST
```