# SQL selecting first record per group

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UTable (
    m_id        TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    u1          TEXT,
    u2          TEXT,
    u3          TEXT,
    -- other stuff, as well as
    gid         INTEGER,
    gt          TEXT,
    d           TEXT,
    timestamp   TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE OTable (
    gid         INTEGER,
    gt          TEXT,
    d           TEXT,
    -- other stuff, such as
    n           INTEGER
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX OTable_idx ON OTable (gid, gt, d);
```

For each record in `OTable` that matches a condition (fixed values of `gid, gt`), I want to join the corresponding record in `UTable` with the minimum timestamp.

What's catching me is that in my final result I don't care about the timestamp, I clearly need to group on `d` (since `gid` and `gt` are fixed), and yet I *do* need to extract `u1, u2, u3` from the selected record.

```
SELECT o.d, u.u1, u.u2, u.u3, o.n
    FROM UTable u
INNER JOIN OTable o
  ON u.gid = o.gid AND u.gt = o.gt AND u.d = o.d
WHERE u.gid = 3 AND u.gt = 'dog night'
GROUP BY u.d
-- and u.timestamp is the minimum for each group
;
```

I think my first step should be just to do the select on `UTable` and then I can join against that.  But even there I'm a bit confused.

```
SELECT u.d, u.u1, u.u2, u.u3
    FROM UTable u
WHERE u.gid = 3 AND u.gt = 'dog night';
```

I want to add `HAVING MIN(u.timestamp)`, but that's not valid.

Any pointers as to what I need to do?

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18725277/833300), but it isn't quite what I need, since I can't group on all the `UTable` values lest I select too many things.

Comment: Postgresql's `DISTINCT ON` is perhaps what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you post a data sample with desired output? Also a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=23c12147eb49841f3d1e50f5677df84e) would be nice!

Comment: Postgres 9.5 has reached EOL last year. Consider upgrading to a current version. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY u.d` (without also listing `u1`, `u2`, `u3`) would only work if `u.d` was the `PRIMARY KEY` (which it is not, and also wouldn't make sense in your scenario). See:

- [Is it possible to have an SQL query that uses AGG functions in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870148/is-it-possible-to-have-an-sql-query-that-uses-agg-functions-in-this-way/7871033#7871033)

I suggest `DISTINCT ON` in a subquery on `UTable` instead:

```sql
SELECT o.d, u.u1, u.u2, u.u3, o.n
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.d)
          u.d, u.u1, u.u2, u.u3
   FROM   UTable u
   WHERE  u.gid = 3
   AND    u.gt = 'dog night'
   ORDER  BY u.d, u.timestamp
   ) u
JOIN   OTable o USING (gid, gt, d);
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If `UTable` is big, at least a multicolumn index on `(gid, gt)` is advisable. Same for `OTable`.
Maybe even on `(gid, gt, d)`. Depends on data types, cardinalities, ...